# Finding all words: Negative Look Behind in Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am currently using Python 2.7 (I'm working with some old code of mine).  And I am trying to get all words via regex, where I can ignore words with apostrophes, like `can't` and `Gary's`. So far I have made all letters in the string lowercase and here's my current regex:

```
r"(?<=\s|^)([a-z]+)(?=\s|$)"
```

I get the following error:

> raise error, v # invalid expression
>
> error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

I also tried:

```
r"(?:\s|^)([a-z]+)(?=\s|$)"
```

But, as you can see on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6EPU7A/1), it doesn't capture the last word.

I know that there are probably better alternatives to doing this, but now I am really curious as to how to do a negative look behind in this situation. However, if you could explain that and offer your own better solution, that'd be fine and appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, just use a negative lookbehind with the opposite character class `\S` (same can be done with the lookahead):

```
r"(?<!\S)([a-z]+)(?!\S)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/czC8GC/1).

A "positive" approach will look less pretty:

```
r"(?:(?<=\s)|^)([a-z]+)(?=\s|$)"
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/czC8GC/2/). The `(?:(?<=\s)|^)` non-capturing group combines 2 zero-width assertion alternatives, `(?<=\s)` that requires a whitespace before the current location, and `^`, matching the start of string.

Comment: Is there anyway to not use a negative?  I'm curious in case I have run into a similar problem in the future.

Comment: Yes, but it does not look tidy.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, could you post that too, by chance?

Comment: Note that you also may use `re.I` flag to match lower and uppercase ASCII letters with `[a-z]`. Also, you may use `[^\W\d_]` instead, it will only match letters and if you use `re.U` flag, that would also match all Unicode letters.